# Is the WaitHandle the best option?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-mvc-3, waithandle

I'm working on an MVC application, that uses some Windows Workflow behind the scenes for automation.

I have implemented some code to wait for the Workflow to complete.  below is a sample app that boils down the problem to its key parts.

The issue doesn't really have to do with the work going on in the WF activity, but more how I'm waiting for it to complete.

*HomeController.cs*

```
    public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult ProcessRequest()
        {
            int[] arr = new int[0];

            var wh = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            var instance = new Activities.SampleCodeActivity();
            var args = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            args.Add("Limit", 25);
            var app = new WorkflowApplication(instance, args);
            app.Completed = resultArgs =>
            {
                var list = (List<int>)resultArgs.Outputs["Primes"];
                arr = list.ToArray();
                wh.Set();
            };
            app.Run();
            wh.WaitOne();
            return Json(arr);
        }
```

*Index.cshtml*

```
    @{ ViewBag.Title = "Index"; }

<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tools = {};
    tools.processRequest = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("ProcessRequest")", type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    };
    $(document).ready(function () {
        tools.processRequest();
    });
</script>
<h2>Index</h2>
```

*SampleCodeActivity.cs*

```
public class SampleCodeActivity : CodeActivity
{
    public InArgument<int> Limit { get; set; }
    public OutArgument<List<int>> Primes { get; set; }
    private List<int> _list = new List<int>();
    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
        var limit = context.GetValue(Limit);
        checkForPrimes(limit);
        context.SetValue(Primes, _list);
    }

    private void checkForPrimes(int limit)
    {
        for (var x = 2; x <= limit; x++)
            if (isPrime(x)) _list.Add(x);   
    }
    private bool isPrime(int value)
    {
        for (var x = value - 1; x > 1; x--)
            if (value % x == 0) return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

My question is regarding the WaitHandle/ManualResetEvent in the Controller Action.  Is there a better way to implement this using Tasks, etc?  I am using .NET 4.5.

Without the WaitHandle in place the Action returns before the workflow has completed.

I am familiar with WaitHandle, but it feels like a klunky solution.

Any help / guidance is appreciated.

Comment: I have not idea, but I am interested to see an answer.  I use waithandles -- and i dont like them.  The feel "gross-er" than a GOTO:

Answer (score 2):

`WaitHandle` is an abstract class providing the ability to wait for access to shared resources at the operating system level.  If you wish to synchronize access at this level, there is no getting away from using it.  However, as you mention, using something like the `ManualResetEvent` can interrupt the flow of your code, making it hard to read and diagnose when things go wrong.

Many of the recent additions to the .NET framework regarding threading attempt to address this issue.  In .NET 4 the notion of `Task` was introduced, which can streamline the code somewhat, and C# 5 built on top of that infrastructure to introduce the `async/await` keywords.  The code below is a simple console application, showing three ways of achieving what you want using `ManualResetEvent`, `Task`'s and `async/await`.

It is important to realize that all three are using the `WaitHandle` class at some level to synchronize the threads, but the readability is improved using `Task`'s and `async/await`.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> results;

        //Using raw Wait Handle
        ManualResetEvent handle = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        Thread thread = new Thread(o =>
            {
                //Long running process
                results = LongRunningTask();
                handle.Set();
            });
        thread.Start();
        handle.WaitOne();

        Console.WriteLine("Thread completed");

        //Using Tasks
        Task<List<int>> task = Task<List<int>>.Factory.StartNew(LongRunningTask);
        results = task.Result;
        Console.WriteLine("Task completed");

        //Using async/await
        results = LongRunningTaskAsync().Result;
        Console.WriteLine("Async Method completed");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static List<int> LongRunningTask()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        return new List<int>();
    }

    public static async Task<List<int>> LongRunningTaskAsync()
    {
        return await Task<List<int>>.Factory.StartNew(LongRunningTask);
    }
}
```